# Regular Expression in PATINDEX That Matches [A-Z] EXCEPT for U

Tags: sql, sql-server, patindex

I am trying to work out a Regular Expression to use in PATINDEX that will match a certain pattern (hence PATINDEX).

I need to match the first 3 characters exactly with 003
The 4th character can be any alpha character EXCEPT for U
 
I have this working for the 003 and A-Z

```
SELECT  PATINDEX('%[0][0][3][A-Za-z]%', '003A654')
```

I tried to negate Uu, but it didn't work, it still sees the pattern.  When I check it on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) it doesn't see it as negating the U unless I put it into it's own group, but that doesn't work either.

```
SELECT  PATINDEX('%[0][0][3][A-Za-z^Uu]%', '003U654')
SELECT  PATINDEX('%[0][0][3][A-Za-z][^Uu]%', '003U654')
```

I know I can do something ugly like match the 003(alpha) using PATINDEX and add `AND SUBSTRING('003U654',4,1) <> 'U'` but I would prefer to do it cleaner if possible.

Comment: Use `'%003[A-TV-Za-tv-z]%'`

Comment: WOULD using PATINDEX('%[0][0][3][Uu]%',...) or LIKE '003U%' be better/faster/more efficient to match the U case?

Comment: For just matching `U` or `u`, yes `%003[Uu]%`  would be the right regex and for excluding `U` or `u` see my answer below

Comment: SQL Server `PATINDEX` doesn't use regular expressions so thinking of them as regular expressions and trying online regex testers isn't going to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your range into 2 and leave `U` and `u` out. Moreover `[0]` is same `0` so no need to use a character class for that.

Your regex be:

```bash
SELECT PATINDEX('%003[A-TV-Za-tv-z]%', '003A654')
```

Comment: Just watch out, some collations like Czech doesn't sort in a-z order so these ranges don't match all characters. I always found it safest to specify the abcde... letters explicitely